# init: is it a user thread or a kernel thread?

Tags: linux, kernel, process, ps, init

init is the first task executed after kernel is loaded, right?
Then who is its owner.

also I can see [swapper/0] [swapper/1] ..... [swapper/7] having pid 0

```
PID    PPID  CPU   TASK    ST  %MEM     VSZ    RSS  COMM
 0      0   0  c180b020  RU   0.0       0      0  [swapper/0]
 0      2   1  f7550ca0  RU   0.0       0      0  [swapper/1]
 0      2   2  f7554bc0  RU   0.0       0      0  [swapper/2]
 0      2   3  f7570ca0  RU   0.0       0      0  [swapper/3]
 0      2   4  f7574bc0  RU   0.0       0      0  [swapper/4]
 0      2   5  f75c8ca0  RU   0.0       0      0  [swapper/5]
 0      2   6  f75ccbc0  RU   0.0       0      0  [swapper/6]
 0      2   7  f75f0ca0  RU   0.0       0      0  [swapper/7]
 1      0   2  f7480000  IN   0.1    4676   2568  init
 2      0   5  f7480ca0  IN   0.0       0      0  [kthreadd]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`init` is a user-space process that always has PID=1 and PPID=0.  It's the first user-space program spawned by the kernel once everything is ready (i.e. essential device drivers are initialised and the root filesystem is mounted).  As the first process launched, it doesn't have a meaningful parent.

The other 'processes' in your extract are indeed kernel tasks.